# FSRA insurance on foreign currency GICs (Ontario/Canada)

Tags: canada, ontario

It seems clear that FDIC insurance covers foreign currency GICs [as of April 2020](https://www.cdic.ca/wp-content/uploads/FAQs-about-changes-to-CDIC-deposit-insurance.pdf), but I can find nothing clear-cut on FSRA (provincial insurance for credit unions) for similar investments.

The [FSRA page](https://www.fsrao.ca/consumers/credit-unions-and-deposit-insurance) says GICs of any term are included but foreign currency deposits are not.

So are foreign-currency GICs insured or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official word (via e-mail from an advisor) is that they are **not** covered.

The assumption seems to be that  they are the same as foreign currency deposits:

> Good Morning Spehro,
>
> No, foreign currency deposits are not covered under FSRA deposit
> insurance. If you have any other questions, don’t hesitate to reach
> out.

Confirmed directly with FSRA, emphasis  added:

> Good morning,
>
> I have provided a link to information on our website.  "Insurable
> Deposits" include GICs, and foreign currency deposits (**which includes
> GICs**) are not covered.  If you have any other questions, please let me
> know.
>
> https://www.fsrao.ca/consumers/credit-unions-and-deposit-insurance
>
> (name and contact information elided)
>
> Credit Union and Prudential | Financial Services Regulatory Authority
> of Ontario (FSRA)

Comment: can you quote anything from the email? does it specify a source for the answer?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep quoted. The "foreign currency deposit" exemption *is* listed on the FSRA website I linked, but nothing about GICs.